# Am I off to a good start in my template function?

Tags: c++

so I am being asked to create a template function with a name, and it has to accept two T objects, then I have to define the parameters to be constant references to those T objects and it has to return the smaller of the two. I am trying to see if I am off to a proper start as this is my first time working with templates.

```
template<class T1, class T2>
T1 minimum(const T1, int size)
{
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T1, class T2>
T1 minimum(const T1, int size)
```

This is a templated function which takes two arguments: the first is of type `T1`, and the second is always an `int`. This function will return a `T1`. The template argument `T2` is unused and likely to cause problems with template inference. At bare minimum, to be useful, this function should be written as

```
template <class T>
T minimum(T arg, int size)
```

However, your prompt asked for *two* `T` reference arguments. It said nothing about taking an `int`. So, instead, I might recommend something like

```
template <class T>
T minimum(const T& arg1, const T& arg2)
```

Now you have two arguments. See if you can figure out how to write the function body.

Answer (score 0):

People here on SO love homework questions, so, we are glad to help.

It is always a good starting point to read the requirements and then to design the implementation.

From

> create a template function with a name, and it has to accept two T objects, then I have to define the parameters to be constant references to those T objects and it has to return the smaller of the two.

This we can split in parts:

1. template    --> OK, we need to define a template
2. function    --> We need to create a *template* function
3. two T objects  --> The function need to have 2 parameters, somehow with type T
4. constant references to T --> We need to write something like "const T&" for the parameter
5. has to return the smaller of the two. --> We need to find, if one element is samllert than the other and the return the smallest

From 1:

`template <class T>`

From 2:

```
template <class T>
something function(something)
```

From 3:

```
template <class T>
something function(T parameter1, T parameter2)
```

From 4:

```
template <class T>
something function(const T& parameter1, const T& parameter2)
```

From 5:

```
template <class T>
T function(const T& parameter1, const T& parameter2) {
    T smallerOfTheTwo;
    if (parameter1 < parameter2)
        smallerOfTheTwo = parameter1;
    if (parameter2 < parameter1)
        smallerOfTheTwo = parameter2;
    if (parameter2 == parameter1)
        smallerOfTheTwo = parameter1;
    return smallerOfTheTwo;
}
```

There was no specification what we should do, if the 2 input values are equal. We assume, that we than can return any of them.